# Classes Inside Modules

Tags: python

Lets say I have the code:

```
class NoneDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        try:
                return super(NoneDict, self).__getitem__(name)
        except:
                return None
```

I want people to be able to create a NoneDict object without writing all this code out. I tried including it in a module and then typed:

```
import nonedict
foo = NoneDict()
```

But it didn't work. How can I make it so someone can import the module and then be able to create a nonedict without typing out all the code?

Comment: Did you try `from nonedict import NoneDict` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import nonedict
foo = nonedict.NoneDict()
```

or

```
from nonedict import NoneDict
foo = NoneDict()
```

or (thanks @Joel Cornett)

```
from nonedict import NoneDict as nd
foo = nd()
```

Comment: You could also do `from nonedict import NoneDict as nd`

Answer (score 2):

[`foo = nonedict.NoneDict()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)